# Database approch in YII

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, dao, query-builder

I am developing my first YII website. I have a couple of doubts about YII database.

There are three methods to query database in yii.

- Database Access Objects
- Query Builder
- Active Record

---

1. Out of these three methods which is the secure and most preferred method?
2. If I have custom queries to perform which method should I prefer?
3. In case of Query Builder queries we explicitly choose table like

   ```
       $user = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
           ->select('id, username, profile')
           ->from('tbl_user') // explicitly choosing the table
           ->join('tbl_profile p', 'u.id=p.user_id')
           ->where('id=:id', array(':id'=>$id))
           ->queryRow();
   ```

   so where should I write query builder queries? Is there any advantage if I write them in corresponding table model?
4. If I use DAO or query builder what class should extend my model?
5. How to validate user inputs if I follow DAO method or query builder method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Depends. All are equally secured if you know how to use them securely.
2. DAO. That's my opinion though.
3. In the models.
4. There are two main model classes in Yii. `CFormModel` and `CModel`. For queries, extend the class with respect to CModel.

Just a note at the end. DAO is the fastest among them. Active record is slowest. On the other hand, active record is more convenient. You are the one who needs to decide what should be the balance.

Comment: Why should we write Query Builder queries in model(table name is specified in the query it self)?

Comment: I don't use query builder anyway. But question is, where you want to write if not in the models?

Comment: Why not write them in the controller?

Comment: No because database queries are not business logic. If you want, you can ofcourse.

Comment: So if I use Query Builder or DAO method I can write queries in any model independent of table, is n't it?(since table name is specified in the query itself)

Comment: yes. but take mintanibility factor into account while doing so. For small site, its ok but for bigger, it may not be.

Comment: Please answer my 4th and 5th question too.. :)

Comment: updated. i am not sure what is your 5th question. User input validation consists range of operations depending upon the data type.

Comment: CFormModel and CActiveRecord are subclass's of CModel

Comment: Yes. But purpose and implementation is different. Use the right tool for the right purpose.

Comment: Wheather CActiveRecord class is only for Active Record method na?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CActiveRecord](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord) for all your requirements.